# How to get DockPanel name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I have a problem and I searched many hours and I did not find useful information on the internet.I have 7 widgets in my website.These widgets are defined as DockPanel. I want user to drop any panel in any zones on my page will save the location.But I have to get dockpanel names to send my database through my webmethod. I try all combination to get my widget names, and I failed.Please help me to solve this issue.

https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientDockManager.GetPanels
https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientControlCollection.GetByName(name)
https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/9448/Common-Concepts/Client-Side-Functionality/Client-Side-Events
https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/9150/ASP-NET-MVC-Extensions/Common-Concepts/Client-Side-API
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T202401/how-to-find-dockpanel-on-the-client-using-javascript

I tried this solution but I did not fix the issue.

getName = function () {

```
        var results = widgetName.exec((this).Object.toString());

        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(results);
        // return (myJSON && myJSON.length > 1) ? myJSON[1] : "";
        return myJSON;
    };
```

it is my minimal getname funtion.I try to convert panelname to object after that turn to string.How can I fix this?

When I run console.log in inspect window,I see everytime undefined or null or one letter.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

All 'widgets' are nothing but Objects and all objects have 'Attributes', the name, id, or whatever, are attributes.
So, try this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("Panel")[0].getAttribute("name");
Console.log(x);
```

Or if you use JQuery:

```
var x = $("#Panel").data("name");
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond,but  still not working. I see undefined on the Inspect window.How can I fix in another way?And also,I want to get name like s.widgetname . The aim is to hold the all panels name .Thanks in advance

Comment: to help ya, gotta need more info about your code and the structure of that widget, mind to share?